# React with Storybook concatenate string not converted to localIdentName

Tags: reactjs, concatenation, react-props, storybook

I am using React with Storybook for component document purpose. I have created a simple Button component. I need to concatenate a string with props. Below is the line what I'm doing.

```
let paletteClass = isStroke ? `${`${style[palette]}Stroke`}` : `${style[palette]}`;
```

Storybook converted CSS classes to some random letters (localIdentName). I'm not sure where can I control it. But, When I `console.log` the above line it returns this,

```
_2h6gtgy1gP7aGpUo9k2c4dStroke
```

You can see a plain **Stroke** string at the end of word. Because of this CSS not worked properly (Undefined). How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try this `${style[palette]}Stroke`, may be the syntax error.

Comment: What is `style`? Where do you get it from? What is the value you expect to have?

Comment: @diedu I have imported CSS file like this `import style from './button.module.css'`. `palette` contains three variants. Primary, Danger & Warning. I have specific CSS for these three palettes in button.module.css file.

Comment: Can you share the CSS code and be more clear about your expectations? Sorry, I don't understand what is the result you're looking for. AFAIK CSS modules produce some kind of compiled CSS classes, so the result looks ok for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible solutions there:

- to have all possible combinations in your `button.module.css` - Primary, Warning, Danger, PrimaryStroke, WarningStroke, DangerStroke; in that case you'll be able to use it this way `` `${style[palette + 'Stroke']}` ``
- another options is to use global class names so they can't be affected by webpack

```
:global(.Primary) {
 // your rules
}
```